# condtional variable among processes using file lock

Tags: c++, c, linux, multiprocessing, mutex

I want to syncronize multiple processes. I come up with two potential approaches:
1. file lock
2. mutex among processes using shared memory

But shared memory is little bit complicated and I'm not sure if I can use it without make side effect to other module running in my process. So I prefer file lock approach.

But file lock only provide `shared lock` and `exclusive lock`, no conditional variable (as far as I know..). Is there any alternative to do so? Or I have no choice but shared memory?

**Added:**

The reason I want a conditional variable is that I want to **limit the number of shared lock holder**.

And I've come up with a way to do so using only a simple exclusive file lock, as shown at the pseudo code below:

```
RETRY:
file_lock.unique_lock();
if (counter == MAX_PROCESS_ALLOW) {
  file_lock.unlock();
  goto RETRY;
}
// successful get into the pool
++counter;
file_lock.unlock();

// do some thing here

// exit the pool
file_lock.unique_lock();
--counter;
file_lock.unlock();
```

but the problem of this approach is the busy query. Or I can choose to sleep, but it's hard to determine the sleep time....

Comment: Can you explain what your actual problem is? Why do the processes need to be synchronized? What are you trying to prevent from happening?

Comment: Also see semaphores

Comment: @DavidSchwartz They are some worker process, and they will run some CPU-consuming task from time to time (when someone submit the task to those process), and I also have other processes in the system running, so I want to limit the max number of active worker processes running tasks so that they won't take too much computing resource from other processes.

Comment: @ZiqiLiu Doesn't your operating system provide some tool for that? This seems like something best done by the OS because it actually knows what else is competing for resources.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Do you mean tune process priority? I'm using Ubuntu 16.

Comment: Sounds exactly like a job for an inter-process semaphore.  Why use anything else?

Comment: @ZiqiLiu Process priority is one tool. There are others.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using,

```
sem_t *sem_open(const char *name, int oflag, mode_t mode, unsigned int value);
int sem_wait(sem_t *sem);
int sem_getvalue(sem_t *sem, int *sval);
int sem_post(sem_t *sem);
int sem_close(sem_t *sem);
int sem_unlink(const char *name);
```

Any process with permissions can modify count, which will free the processes waiting for a lock.  This will allow a complex evaluation.  Setting "value" within sem_open(...), will determine the number of processes that can share a lock.  See man pages for details.  There are a number of supporting functions.  The following code is an example.  If you build and execute it more than 4 times, then you will see the late starters wait until the early starters complete.

Note that /dev/shm/sem.test_sem is the shared resource under Debian Buster with the Linux kernel.  The code example follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <fcntl.h>           /* For O_* constants */
#include <sys/stat.h>        /* For mode constants */
#include <semaphore.h>

// For Debian Buster, the shared sem is found at /dev/shm/sem.test_sem

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   printf("Starting\n");

    sem_t *sem;
    sem = sem_open("/test_sem", O_CREAT, 0600, 3);q
    if(sem == SEM_FAILED){
        printf("SEM_FAILED\n");
        return -1;
    }
    // sem_unlink("/test_sem"); return 0;  // Use this to remove /dev/shm/sem.test_sem
    sem_wait(sem);
    for(int i = 0; i < 20 ; i++){
        int current_sem_value;
        int error_code = sem_getvalue(sem, &current_sem_value);
        //printf("sem_getvalue return value: %d\n", error_code);
        if(error_code){
            printf("Sem not valid!\n");
        }
        printf("Sem count: %d \n", current_sem_value);
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep(1);
    }

    sem_post(sem);
    sem_close(sem);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that sem_unlink(...) will remove a semaphore from the file system.